# Value of $\theta$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the roots of the equation:
$$z^4 + 4=0$$

According to De Moivre's theorem:

$$w_k = (r)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{i\phi_k}$$
$$\phi_k = \frac{\theta + 2 \pi k}{4}$$

---

Since $$z=(-4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$r = |z| = 16$$

$$w_k = 16\cos(\frac{\theta + 2 \pi k}{4}) + i \sin(\frac{\theta + 2\pi k}{4})$$

But $\theta = Arg(z) = ?$

Comment: $Arg(z) = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)$ is the principle argument of a complex number $z = x + iy$, in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: How is $|z|=16$?

Comment: Since $z^4=-4$, $z^4$ has argument $\theta=\pi$, And the modulus of $z^4$ is $4$, so the modulus of $z$ is $4^{1/4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z^4+4=0\Longleftrightarrow z^4=-4\Longleftrightarrow z^4=|-4|e^{\arg(-4)i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(4e^{(2\pi k+\pi)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\Longleftrightarrow z=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}(2\pi k+\pi)i}$$

Where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-3$

So, the solutions are:

$$z_0=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}(2\pi\cdot0+\pi)i}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}=1+i$$
$$z_1=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}(2\pi\cdot1+\pi)i}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}=-1+i$$
$$z_2=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}(2\pi\cdot2+\pi)i}=\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{3\pi i}{4}}=-1-i$$
$$z_3=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}(2\pi\cdot3+\pi)i}=\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}=1-i$$